# Share a Net::IMAP connection between controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

I have only one controller and some actions in it to handle different functionalities related to IMAP. So my problem is I don't want to create a separate connection for every action. For example in an action I can do something like(it is not the actual code):

```
def index
 @imap = Net::IMAP.new(server, 993, true)
 @imap.login(user, password)
 @imap.select("INBOX")
end
```

Again in another action inside the same controller, if I need to do something related to IMAP then I will have to create the `@imap` variable again.

I am working with IMAP first time so as per my understanding `new` method in each action will create another connection to the server and I have heard google has connection limit (15) for the number of IMAP connections.

I can not serialize this connection object or store it in any other service like Redis or Memcached or cache it, So how can I create this connection once and use it all other actions, at least actions inside the same controller if possible? If not possible then any other solutions to handle this problem?

And of course I can cache the data I need from the mailbox but that can't help much since there are some other actions which won't need the data, it will need to do so some operations in the mailbox like deleting mails, so that will need the connection instance.

Comment: Do you want to store the connection between the requests? Or do you just want a way to open a new connection from any of the actions in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you create a service object (singleton) that wraps you `Net::IMAP`. You can stick it in `app/services/imap_service.rb` or something like that. For an example on what that would look like:

```
require 'singleton' # This is part of the standard library
require 'connection_pool' # https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool

class IMAPService
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @imap = ConnectionPool.new(size: 15) { Net::IMAP.new(server, 993, true) }
  end

  def inbox(user, password)
    @imap.with do |conn|
      conn.login(user, password)
      conn.select("INBOX")
    end
  end
end
```

You access this singleton like `IMAPService.instance` e.g. `IMAPService.instance.inbox(user, password)`. I added in the connect_pool gem as per our discussion to make sure this is thread safe. There is no `attr_reader :imap` on IMAPService. However, you can add one so that you can directly access the connection pool in your code if you don't want to include all of the necessary methods here (although I recommend using the service object if possible). Then you can do `IMAPService.instance.imap.with { |conn| conn.login(user, password) }` and don't need to rely on methods in IMAPService.

It's worth noting that you don't have to use the `Singleton` mixin. There is a really good article on [Implementing "the lovely" Singleton](http://ieftimov.com/singleton-pattern) which will show you both ways to do it.

Comment: This looks good so I will try it but still I will wait for any other answer. If i don't get any better answer then I will accept yours.

Comment: Nope, that's just a habit- I removed it. I also updated my comment to suggest doing the service object first rather than the application controller object because it is guaranteed to keep its state which the other answer pointed out. We also have two different styles of writing singletons (which is covered in the article I linked), but I prefer mine because it's much easier to understand when taking a quick read through. There won't be a performance issue, and you can just do it manually if it is (it won't be though). However, I generally advise against optimizing unless it is a bottleneck.

Comment: Using multithread web-server like Puma, singleton may cause some unexpected behaviour if new request on `IMAPService` is started before previous is finished. All singletones are shared resources and could be used very carefully - very likely you don't want to display inbox of user A to user B. Another option here is using something like `connection_pool` that creates few connections to mail server on startup and every connection from the pool could be used exclusively.

Comment: @Semjon would doing all operations inside of a thread work?  E.g. `Thread.new { @imap.login(u, p); @imap.select('INBOX') }`

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation above, I meant another thing - in case you use Puma in multithread mode, the singleton object of `IMAPService` could be used in the same time by two(or more) different users of your web-application. In this case `IMAPService` may authorize user A and user B asks to fetch emails. `IMAPService` will return emails of user A and display them to user B. I would not like to give a code snippet because it is highly depends on your needs. Just wanted to aware from using singleton. Please have a look to abstract 
 implementation https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool

Comment: @Semjon I had the same concern about the singleton objects of `IMAPService` that it might sometime display data of a user to another user, that is why I dropped that idea before posting question here. I don't have much experience of threaded environments but from what I read, this did not look safe. Still I am going to evaluate that and the check `connection_pool`.

Comment: @Sajan I updated the entire answer to reflect our discussion. We still need to use a singleton, but now it uses connection pooling to make sure it keeps state and doesn't go over the 15 connection limit.

Comment: @Dbz Thanks, I will check it out and try it in next couple of days.

Comment: @Dbz I am yet to try this but this but I was thinking to use an existing [gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem to avoid writing some IMAP methods myself. It takes the email and token as a parameter while instantiating like `Gmail.connect(:xoauth2, 'email@domain.com', 'token')` . Any idea how we do that with your code? I know this is out of scope of original question, that is why I am asking you in comment.

Comment: Yes, it would be very similar. You still use the wrapper service class with connection pooling to make sure you don't go over the 15 connection limit. You can use your singleton to run `GmailService.instance.gmail.connect!(username, password) {|gmail| ... play with gmail ... }`  or you can add methods onto your `GmailService` so that you can do specific tasks such as getting the inbox e.g. `GmailService.instance.inbox(username, password)`.

Comment: @Dbz Since I did not get any better answer and your answer is good enough as per me,  I am awarding the bounty to you.

Comment: Thank you @Sajan, is this solution not enough to be considered accepted? Are there still related issues I can help with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the connection to stay open between requests you can not store it as an instance variable in your controller since each request will have its own instance of the controller.

One way to store the connection is to use a singleton.

Here is an example:

```
class ImapService

  attr_accessor :imap

  def initialize
    @imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.gmail.com", 993, true)
    @imap.login("username@gmail.com", "password")
    @imap.select("INBOX")
  end

  @@instance = ImapService.new
  private_class_method :new

  def self.instance
    return @@instance
  end
end
```

This will open the connection the first time you access it, and if you access it again, it will use the old connection.

You would access the imap variable with `ImapService.instance.imap` anywhere in your application.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have a concern, can you say that it is thread safe ? And expose a user's imap connection to another user in multi threaded mode of puma since this will class be shared by default? also please read comments of Semjon on the other answer.

Comment: This solution could also have some unexpected behavior in a multithreaded environment. 

In my example, it would share the same connection, and with multiple users, that would be a problem, I will update my answer with a better solution.